# Need function that update returndate

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

Im trying to create a function that will update the return value depending on what bookType it is. This function should be triggerd when a book is loaned.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8ttY.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlsrC.png]

This is what I have at the moment.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufn_BReturn_date(@Book_ID int)

RETURNS DATE 
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Return_date DATE;
DECLARE @bookType INT;
SELECT @BookType = b.BookType
FROM Book b
WHERE b.Book_ID = @Book_ID; 
    IF (@BookType = 1)
    SET @Return_date = DATEADD(MONTH, 2, cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date))
    ELSE IF (@BookType = 2)
    SET @Return_date = DATEADD(MONTH, 3, cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date))
    ELSE
    SET @Return_date = cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date)
    RETURN @Return_date
END;
```

Comment: Functions are not triggered. But you can write a trigger on a table that executes your function. However it is not at all clear what you want to happen here. This could definitely be simplified to a single select statement with a case expression. Then it could be an inline table valued function instead of the slower scalar function. If you really need some help you need to provide some details. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Wouldn't return date be an attribute of the loan and not the book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to update values in existing rows, do something like this:

```
update Book
set Return_date =
    dateadd(month, case BookType when 1 then 2 when 2 then 3 else 0 end, current_timestamp)
where Return_date is null; -- ??
```

You can certainly put a similar update inside a trigger on the `Loan` table or wherever is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `FUNCTION`s in SQL Server are strictly limited to read-only operations, so you can't even `EXEC` a sproc from a function ([third-party hacks notwithstanding](https://github.com/zzzprojects/Eval-SQL.NET/wiki/SQL-Server-Function-(UDF)-%7C-Execute-stored-procedure,-run-dynamic-SQL-and-modify-table-state-within-a-SQL-Function)).

What you want is a `TRIGGER ON UPDATE`.